# passing more than 1 value through AJAX to VB.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I'm trying to pass more than 1 value through AJAX to VB.NET.

I'm currently passing 1 value through perfectly fine but when I try the second one it errors.

```
var form = document.getElementById("OrderForm"),
    inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    value = [],
    name = [];

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "hidden") {
        value.push(inputs[i].value)
        name.push(inputs[i].name)

        if (value[i] !== "") {
            console.log(name[i], " = ", value[i]);
            //args = '{"value":"' + arr[i] + '"Name":"' + arr[i] + '"}';
            //args = '{"Value":"' + value[i] + '"}';
            //args = 'Name=' + name[i] + '&Value=' + alue[i];

            args = '{ "Value":' + value[i] + ', "Value":' + value[i] + '}'

            aj('payment', returnFunc, args, failedCallBack);
        }
    }
}

function aj(funcName, retFunc, arguments, failedCallBack) {
var retval;
var funcName = funcName;
retval = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '../PaymentGateway.asmx/' + funcName,
    data: arguments,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: retFunc,
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        if (c == 'Unauthorized') {
            //ShowErrorMSG('Error, please login again', a.responseText);
        } else if (c != 'abort') {

        }
    }
});
return retval;
}

function failedCallBack(res) {

}
```

and i'm passing them into my VB.NET function.

```
Public Function payment(Value As String, Name As String) As String
```

Comment: You're passing Value two times? Should it not be `args = '{ "Value":' + value[i] + ', "Name":' + name[i] + '}'`?

Comment: Might be worth including the error.

Answer (score 0):

the argument being passed through was incorrect.

```
args = '{"Value":"' + value + '", "Name":"' + name + '"}';
```

was the correct way.